# Initialization array of two dimensional arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11

How to initialize array of two dimensional arrays in C++ (defined like in code below)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

typedef int arr3by6Int[3][6];
typedef arr3by6Int arr3xarr3by6Int[3];

void print3by6(arr3by6Int arr)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        {
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    arr3by6Int a = {
        {1,2,3,4,5,6},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {2,2,2,2,2,2}
    };

    arr3by6Int b = {
        {2,2,3,4,5,6},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {2,2,2,2,2,2}
    };

    arr3by6Int c = {
        {3,2,3,4,5,6},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {2,2,2,2,2,2}
    };

    arr3xarr3by6Int d = { a, b, c };

    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        print3by6(d[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I get these errors:

> `$ g++ -std=c++11  arrays.cpp -o arrays`
>   `arrays.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, const char**)’:`
>   `arrays.cpp:39:32: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer`
>   `arrays.cpp:39:32: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer`
>   `arrays.cpp:39:32: error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer`

Comment: the error says it all

Comment: C-style arrays cannot be initialized directly from other arrays, nor can they be passed by value as a function argument or returned from a function.

Comment: Re-write it without the typedefs and it might be more obvious why it's wrong.

Comment: I feel like use of the `typedef` operator should require a licence first. It can very quickly complicate and obfuscate data structures.

Comment: oh, I see now. 
Thank you Jonathan Potter

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have `#include <array>` in your code, so you should use it. Change your types to use `std::array<>`:

```
typedef std::array<std::array<int, 6>, 3> arr3by6Int;
typedef std::array<arr3by6Int, 3> arr3xarr3by6Int;
```

Then, update your initialization lists to match:

```
    arr3by6Int a = {
        std::array<int, 6>{1,2,3,4,5,6},
        std::array<int, 6>{0,0,0,0,0,0},
        std::array<int, 6>{2,2,2,2,2,2}
    };

    arr3by6Int b = {
        std::array<int, 6>{2,2,3,4,5,6},
        std::array<int, 6>{0,0,0,0,0,0},
        std::array<int, 6>{2,2,2,2,2,2}
    };

    arr3by6Int c = {
        std::array<int, 6>{3,2,3,4,5,6},
        std::array<int, 6>{0,0,0,0,0,0},
        std::array<int, 6>{2,2,2,2,2,2}
    };
```

In most cases, an object of "C style" array type will degrade to the pointer to the array's first element when used in an expression. Your way of initializing `d` is attempting to initialize the 3 matrices with pointer values, which won't work.

A `std::array` is a class, so it won't degrade in that way.

Comment: Thank you, that's exacly what I was looking for.